# Composer -- can a package get its own version

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm distributing a PHP package with Composer. Composer versions packages via their git tags.

I'd like my package to send its version number in the user agent string used when it makes HTTP requests.

Is it possible for my package, once installed as a dependency of another package, to get its own currently installed version number, presuming that this version number is not hard coded anywhere in the source code?

When the package in question is the root package, I can get the version number at install/update time, via a post-package-install/post-package-update script. An event is passed to that from which I can get the currently installed version:

```
public static function write(\Composer\Script\CommandEvent $event)
{
    $composer = $event->getComposer();
    $localRepository = $composer->getRepositoryManager()->getLocalRepository();
    $package = $composer->getPackage($localRepository, 'my/package-name', null);

    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/../version', $package->getVersion());
}
```

However, for [security reasons](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1193), scripts of dependencies aren't run when installing/updating a parent package, and so this won't fly.

One possible line would be to run `composer show -i my/package-name` and parse out the version number, but this is not very portable. (Where is the PHP executable? Where is the composer.phar file? etc)

Another might be to have Composer itself as a dependency, and use some of its own logic as in the code example above. But it is a lot of bloat to include Composer itself as a dependency.

I saw in Composer's own source code that it specifies its own version as `'@package_version@'`, but as far as I can tell this is only for Composer itself, and is replaced with its version number when Composer compiles itself into a phar file.

I could parse the version number out of the composer.lock file in the root package. This seems messy, but I think this is what I'll do for now.

Are there any other solutions? I get the feeling there's something very simple I'm missing.

Comment: Why not have it hardcoded as a constant within your release?

Comment: That means an extra commit to bump the release number to the release version, then another to bump the commit to a development version right after. I find this messy, and I'm likely to forget to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like https://github.com/mcuelenaere/composer-revision-plugin: this generates a PHP class containing the git revision of all composer dependencies at build-time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It's not clear to me whether this would work as a dependency of my library (which would be a dependency of whatever project is being built), or if it needs to be another direct dependency of the root project. Do you know off hand?

Comment: I didn't get as far as seeing if this works from a sub-dependency, but came across the issue that it'll only tell me the commit hash of each package. What I want is the tag name. So I'm afraid this is no good. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, that's why I said you could do something *like* that project. PRs are welcome however!

As this listens to the PRE_AUTOLOAD_DUMP event, it should work for both a direct dependency of the library or the root project (untested however).

Comment: Right, yes, I see.